# Turning while + if else to simpler std::remove_if

Tags: c++

I am trying to clean up some loops, and move from while and if/else into std::remove_if and have never done this before, can anyone show me how to turn the below into a remove_if that will achieve the same results? Ideally I want to eliminate the if(obj->IsQueuedForRemoval).

Thank you in advance!

Initial:

```
void ObjectCollection::ProcessRemovals()
{
    bool removed = false;

    auto objIterator = objects.begin();
    while (objIterator != objects.end())
    {
        auto obj = *objIterator;

        if (obj->IsQueuedForRemoval())
        {
            objIterator = objects.erase(objIterator);
            removed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ++objIterator;
        }
    }
    if (removed)
    {
        drawables.ProcessRemovals();
        collidables.ProcessRemovals();
    }
}
```

Comment: Outside of the need for the erase/remove idiom, it's not clear why you would be unable to just use `remove_if` via its apparent interface. So what problems are you having with making it work?

Comment: @NicolBolas The part I'm getting tripped up on is how I can keep the bool, trigger it if it removes anything and only go to drawables and collidables process removals if it was removed from there.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I could remove it all and just change to 

objects.erase(
    std::remove_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(), IsQueueForRemoval()),
    objects.end());

right?

Comment: If `IsQueueForRemoval()` returns a predicate, then yes.

Comment: @airhoodz I think it would be better if you used a lambda, since `IsQueueForRemoval` seems to be a non-static member function, and it is just easier to use a lambda in that case.

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

> The part I'm getting tripped up on is how I can keep the bool, trigger it if it removes anything and only go to drawables and collidables process removals if it was removed from there.

`std::remove_if` returns an iterator to end of the range of not removed elements. You can split the erase-remove into two steps:

```
auto it = std::remove_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(),predicate)
bool removed = (it != objects.end());
if (removed) {
     objects.erase(it,objects.end());
     drawables.ProcessRemovals();
     collidables.ProcessRemovals();
}
```

Where `predicate` can be a lambda that checks if the object is queued for removal (assuming `IsQueuedForRemoval` is `const`):

```
auto predicate = [](const Object& obj){ return obj.IsQueuedForRemoval();};
```

I'll leave it to you to adjust the lambda in case the containers elements type is something else than `Object`.

Comment: objects.erase(
  std::remove_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(), []() {bool queuedForRemoval;}), objects.end());

would that be correct? queuedForRemoval is the variable that is returned by IsQueuedForRemoval

Comment: @airhoodz the lamdba has to return something (i will edit in a second), and if you want to know if something has been removed you either have to erase-remove in two steps or compare the size of the container afterwards

Comment: @airhoodz well, actually I cannot tell you how the correct lambda would look like. Your question misses a [mcve]. What is the type of elements in the container?

Comment: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects; that's that Objects is, and Object has the bool function of IsQueuedForRemoval that returns a bool variable queuedForRemoval like so...   


bool Object::IsQueuedForRemoval()
{
    return queuedForRemoval;
}

Comment: That tells me that obj expression must have a pointer type, and also I think std::erase should be objects.erase right?

Comment: @airhoodz sorry that was a typo, fixed it, and yes it has to be `objects.erase`

Comment: I had to remove const there too I think, but removing const removed all errors.

And also, std::erase(it,objects.end()); should be objects.erase right? Otherwise I get a "not a member of std" error

Comment: @airhoodz yes I also fixed the `erase` in the answer. If you had to remove const, it might be that `IsQueuedForRemoval` is not `const` (it should be)

Comment: I did have to remove const, during complie I get the following.....   bool ObjectCollection::ProcessRemovals::<lambda>::operator ()(object &) const: cannot convert argument 1 from std::shared_ptr<object> to Object &

Comment: @airhoodz more ontopic: the predicate has to accept a parameter of type that you get when dereferencing an iterator (possibly involving conversions, but most of the time it is just the type of the elements in the container)

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right, this is my first time working with shared pointers, vectors, I've never worked on remove_if and I've never used lambda. It's been a frustrating bug that I'm trying to alleviate, and I understood the error, the predicate and I didn't word my reply well by saying I didn't get how to fix it and gave up fast.

I think auto predicate = [](std::shared_ptr<Object> const& ptr) {return ptr->IsQueuedForRemoval();}; should solve the problem?

Comment: @airhoodz I still cannot know if that will solve the problem, because your question still misses a mcve. (i am more on the complaining side again ;)

Comment: @airhoodz look, when you want to know how to apply the erase-remove idom to a container then you should write an example that does only that nothing else. Whether this will later be done inside a class working on a member of that class does not matter at this point. Once you remove everything that is not relevant for the piece you are trying to understand you will have a mcve. Often creating a mcve is all you have to do to identify the problem yourself, if you dont you have a small example you can post here